# OpenCR Board Can't Publish, Can Subscribe (WSL)

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-melodic, turtlebot, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Lately I've been trying to follow the tutorials at [the robotis manual](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/slam/) to learn about ROS and Turtlebot3. I have a Turtlebot3 Burger.

### My setup

- Using ROS Melodic
- PC OS: WSL Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
- Tb3: Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu 18.04 **Server** Bionic
- OpenCR 1.0 firmware: v1.2.3
- ... Let me know to add any other relevant info.

---

### Question

While trying to get SLAM to work, I was experiencing a common issue of no transform from odom to base_footprint. Upon more investigation, I found that I couldn't see any odom data through `rostopic echo odom` and `rostopic hz odom` showed that there were never any messages.

However, I know that I can command the turtlebot using keyboard teleop. I just can't receive any messages that are sent "from" the OpenCR board. Why is this?

I have explored the idea of this being a time-sync issue. I have checked to make sure my ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME are correct on all machines.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

--**EDIT 0**: This doesn't seem like a cross-computer issue to me, but rather something with rosserial that is causing topics to not have messages published.--

**EDIT 1**: actually, it is a cross-machine issue!

**EDIT 2**: When I use `ROS_IP` instead of `ROS_HOSTNAME` and set ROS_MASTER_URI to be http://`ip of pc`:11311 I don't see any data on the topics from the OpenCR; when I run everything on the RPi, I do see data.

**EDIT 3**: I am able to publish from RPi to PC and vice versa, but nothing comes from the rosserial_python node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324374/opencr-board-can%27t-publish,-can-subscribe-(wsl)/) by [ros_noob_corgi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41936/ros_noob_corgi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have figured out my answer: issues were due to my use of WSL.

---

Originally posted by [ros_noob_corgi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41936/ros_noob_corgi/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0